# Trying to use gdal2xyz in QGIS: "Error:Wrong command"

Tags: qgis, gdal, error

I am using the following command

```
gdal2xyz.dy -csv /Users/me/Downloads/esp_gpwv3_pcount_ascii_25/espp00ag.bil    /Users/documents/tttest.csv
```

in the commander, but I get the following error message and nothing happens "Error:Wrong command". I have installed GdalTools plugin.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is the gdal2xyz **.dy** a typo in your question? Should be **.py**, I guess.

Comment: gdal2xyz.py doesn't work either...

Comment: Not sure where you entered the command. Have you tried it in the OSGEO4W shell?

Comment: If you used Processing commander, you better try `Processing -> GDAL/OGR -> Conversion -> gdal2xyz`

Comment: Thank you Andre for your help! Sorry to be so slow, but I don't have a GDAL/OGR option under processing.

Comment: I was entering the "gdal2xyz.py -csv..." line in the commander (under "processing") and I have also tried in the Terminal window, but it doesn't work.... There is clearly something fundamental that I don't understand...

Comment: At the bottom of the processing toolbox, you have to switch the dropdown field to `Advanced interface`.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot! I'll summarise the answer for the other beginners.

Comment: I am getting a problem as a result, I got -1000 elevation in every coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I now know how to do it thanks to Andre's help and direction, and here is a summary of the steps:

- in QGIS, in plugins, add the gdal2xyz
- in processing, click on toolbox, then search for the gdal2xyz algorithm
- click on it, specify the input and output files, press run, and that's it - deadly simple to do, once you know how to do it!